# using hive to select data within large range partitions

Tags: hadoop, hql, hive, hadoop-partitioning

I've came out some problem using hive to select data within large range partitions

Here's the HQL I want to execute:

```sql
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE summary_T partition(DateRange='20131222-20131228')
select col1, col2, col3 From RAW_TABLE 
where cdate between '20131222' and '20131228' 
and (trim(col1) IS NULL or trim(col1)='')
and length(col2)=12;
```

"cdate" is the partition of table RAW_TABLE

but it stucks after giving me the job id

Once I change it into:

```sql
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE summary_T partition(DateRange='20131222-20131228')
select col1, col2, col3 From RAW_TABLE 
where cdate between '20131222' and '20131225' 
and (trim(col1) IS NULL or trim(col1)='')
and length(col2)=12;
```

then it starts work

Is there any solution that can help me execute the first HQL?

thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem, and tried using `CLUSTER BY 'partition_column'` at the end of my SELECT statement. After using it I could execute my INSERT for a substantial greater date range.

So if you change your query to:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE summary_T partition(DateRange='20131222-20131228')
select col1, col2, col3 From RAW_TABLE 
where cdate between '20131222' and '20131228' 
and (trim(col1) IS NULL or trim(col1)='')
and length(col2)=12
CLUSTER BY DateRange;
```

The performance shall improve.

For explanation on how CLUSTER BY helps a query, you can go through this manual page which explains it in detail:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SortBy

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience!!
I'll try out this method then report it back.

Comment: I get an error above:

    FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10004]: Line 6:11 Invalid table alias or column reference 'DateRange': (possible column names are: col1, col2, col3)

looks like it can't execute the 'CLUSTER BY' with partition column

Comment: Just try to execute the Select statement with CLUSTER BY first.. In my case, I was able to execute the INSERT. It did not throw any such error.